# How do I calculate the sum of transaction inputs?

Tags: raw-transaction, transaction-input

I am attempting to calculate the mining fee of a transaction, given it's unsigned transaction hex by taking difference between the sum of the inputs and outputs.

I also have access to an array of `Txout` and `Txin` blobs.

Taking the sum of the the `Txout` array is easy, as first eight bytes is the value of the output, but I do not know how to get the value of an input for a `Txin`.

The format of the `Txin` blobs is that which is described on the [bitcoin.it](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#General_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_input_of_a_transaction_-_Txin) wiki --

```
Previous Transaction hash   ||  32 bytes
Previous Txout-index        || 4 bytes
Txin-script                 || 1-9 bytes
Txin-script                 || arbitrary number of bytes
sequence_no                 ||  4 bytes
```

How can I get the value of each input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look up the previous unspent transaction output using the hash and txout-index, and this output contains the amount in satoshis which is provided in entirety as input for the transaction.